what's the point of CODECOPY opcode
CODECOPY is used to copy the executing program's opcode onto the memory. I wonder what's the use of this though. Is there a deployed example where CODECOPY is useful?

Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/143698/opcodes-how-is-work-codecopy.

A case, I can think of is during the contract deployment.
It stores the runtime bytecode into memory and that bytecode is returned later.
More details here - https://www.zaryabs.com/journey-of-smart-contracts-from-solidity-code-to-bytecodes-2nd-section/

CODECOPY returns bytecode of a smart contract
it could be a good functionality when you want to dynamically load and execute code from another contract. for example for creating upgradeable contracts, where you can change the logic of a contract without having to redeploy the entire contract. By using CODECOPY, you can copy the bytecode of a new contract into the current contract's memory and then execute it using DELEGATECALL or CALL.
Also it has a use to safely clean memory like this example.
Here is a python implementation of CODECOPY.
And Here is another use case of CODECOPY in contract factory method.
